# localhost, 127.0.0.1 and hosts file are not working on a specific port

Tags: windows, dns, localhost, hosts

I'm struggling with this problem for a while.

When I enter `http://localhost:680/local` in chrome's address bar, the web page is loaded and everything works as expected. But when I enter anything else including `http://127.0.0.1:680/local` I get an error: `ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`.

update: Today `localhost` stopped working as well.

[image]

My backend code isn't called and there is nothing received as I see in the DevTools:

[image]

This was working yesterday, and I don't know what has changed in my system.

**If I change my port to 681 it works.**

This is particularly important because I need to open the web page with URL prefix such as `admin.mysite.net:680/local` or `user.mysite.net:680/local` but adding these names to the `hosts` file doesn't do anything.

### What I have tried:

### ping:

When I ping `127.0.0.1` it tells me the IPv6: `Reply from ::1: time<1ms` and I've disabled IPv6 in registry but still it's showing `::1`:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\DisabledComponents = 0x20`

I can ping all names in hosts they all resolve to `127.0.0.1` and I can see them all in `ipconfig /displaydns`

### hosts:

I followed [these instructions](https://serverfault.com/a/452269/151294)

I can edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` but it doesn't make any difference. When I add or remove `127.0.0.1 localhost` or other value I always get the same result. I created a new single line ANSI file with this content `127.0.0.1 aaa` but `aaa:680/local` gives me the same error.

### other:

I also tried `ipconfig /flushdns` and `ipconfig /registerdns`.

I executed `netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1` and it added the IP address.

I tried incognito and I cleared chrome data.

I read that there was a bug with http-server so I tried `npm uninstall http-server` and 
`npm install http-server@0.9.0`.

I have no proxy, no automatic configuration script in LAN settings, no firewall.

I'm out of ideas. What else can I try?

Comment: As long as the request is reaching the server, it means all components are working perfectly except the server itself. Can you check is it an issue related to ``CROS`` (cross-origin resource sharing). I had a similar issue when once I was making a web app, but the server is kind enough to send the error back, and I am not sure whether the server you installed through npm is.

Comment: @MohithReddy it's our own app which is working everywhere else, but not on my PC. I've updated my question, I think it's related to one specific port.

Comment: @MohithReddy you were absolutely right my friend :) it was another one of our services blocking the backend. After stopping the service it suddenly started working.

Comment: I am glad that you finally fixed the issue. But are you sure that the problem is related to CROS or that service is doing something else to give you invalid responses

Comment: @MohithReddy after reading about it I'm not sure (if I understood correctly CORS addresses browser access, not any resource such as httpclient or a file) but to me it looks like the other service was denying some resource from the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be related to resource sharing or as Mohith mentioned CROS (cross-origin resource sharing).

There was another service in background which was somehow blocking some resources (probably port 680) denying access to the backend. Stopping the service fixed the issue.